# How to change progress bar value by dragging mouse in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a media player and I'm trying to change value of Progress Bar using mouse cursor.
what i want is to set the value of progress bar where mouse cursor points after clicking + Dragging.

Comment: i'm trying to use mouseposition.x on progress bar mousemove event

Comment: Have you tried AddHandler -> MouseDown/MouseMove/MouseUp/MouseClick, AddressOf [Name of your Methods] to control progressBar1.Value, taking account of .Minimum and .Maximum and margin of the progressBar user Interface... Don't expect from someone to [write the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of your application. SO is not a code project automatic generator.

Comment: nope i dont expect this lol :v by the way i got my solution someone is good than you :v btw this program was just wast know how not for sale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A progress bar is not the correct control to use for this.  You should use a TrackBar instead.

But it can be made to work, with about -10 elegance points.  The trickiest problem with ProgressBar is that it animates progress.  That makes it slow to respond to your mouse moves.  That animation can be disabled, but not perfectly.  Closest you can get is:

```
Private Shared Sub ChangeProgress(bar As ProgressBar, e As MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim mousepos = Math.Min(Math.Max(e.X, 0), bar.ClientSize.Width)
        Dim value = CInt(bar.Minimum + (bar.Maximum - bar.Minimum) * mousepos / bar.ClientSize.Width)
        '' Disable animation, if possible
        If value > bar.Value And value < bar.Maximum Then
            bar.Value = value + 1
            bar.Value = value
        Else
            bar.Value = value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And call it from MouseDown and MouseMove event handlers:

```
Private Sub ProgressBar1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ProgressBar1.MouseMove
    ChangeProgress(ProgressBar1, e)
End Sub

Private Sub ProgressBar1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ProgressBar1.MouseDown
    ChangeProgress(ProgressBar1, e)
End Sub
```

It is workable, you'll notice that getting to 100% is a bit awkward.  But, really, use a TrackBar instead.  It was made to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer i'm trying to look for an alternate control like trackbar but it looks ugly maybe i have to use custom controls